# How to use currency pipe to get values upto 2 decimal digits in component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-pipe

I have a values like 54781.7622000 , 1123.11. I want this values in a format like $54781.76 , $1123.11.

```
//import currency pipe
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common'

//initialize  in constructor
constructor(private cp: CurrencyPipe)

this.formatedOutputValue = this.cp.transform(parseInt(this.outputValue));
```

I have tried sum extra parameters after this value like.

```
this.formatedOutputValue = this.cp.transform(parseInt(this.outputValue),1.2-2);
```

But doesnt workout.

Answer (score 11):

You are not passing all the needed parameters to the `transform()`

This is what the currency pipe `transform()` accepts in Angular (Source: [Angular codebase](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L195))

```js
transform(value: any, currencyCode?: string, display: 'code'|'symbol'|'symbol-narrow'|string|boolean = 'symbol', digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string)
```

You can fix your issue by passing the right data to the `transform()` like below.

```js
this.formatedOutputValue = this.cp.transform(this.outputValue, 'USD', 'symbol', '1.2-2');
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-in-component). You can also see how to directly use the pipe in the template in this example.

Comment: and what if the value is suppose $100.00 and i only want to show $100 only

Comment: Why would you want to do that for currency? It would be better to leave it with 2 decimal places. If you still want to do that you can use ````this.formatedOutputValue.replace(/.00/g, "")````.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it using [currency pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) only

```
this.cp.transform(this.data,'USD','symbol','1.2-2')
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-n7wj5n)

Answer (score 1):

You can create pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'formatedOutputValue'
})
export class FormatedOutputValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
  return value.toFixed(2).replace(/[.,]00$/, "");
 }
}
```

In your template:

```
 <div>{{data.value | formatedOutputValue}}</div>
```

Comment: how do i get the currency symbol ?

Comment: @swapniljain you can use built-in angular pipe to get currency symbol

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the Currency pipe in your template like this:

```
{{ outputValue | currency }}
```

The default decimal point is 2 if a currency code is not specified.

Angular has [excellent documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) on how to properly use their CurrencyPipe.

Comment: The question is about using this pipe in the component.